# Access array defined in external file from perl

Tags: arrays, perl

I have a perl pre_installer.conf program for storing config.

```
use strict;

$VAR::phpmodules = ("php5-curl", "php5-mcrypt", "php-abc");
1;
```

I have included this file and accessed `$VAR::phpmodules`

```
require 'pre_installer.conf';
print $VAR::phpmodules;
```

But it prints only 'php-abc'. That is the last item only? Why didn't it print the whole array?

Comment: Out of interest - if you `perl -c` that module, does it work?

Comment: Actually, never mind. You need `warnings` turned on too, for perl to warn you about the bad syntax on that line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because

```
$VAR::phpmodules = ("php5-curl", "php5-mcrypt", "php-abc");
```

isn't doing what you think it is. It's assigning the last element in the list.

```
my $thing = ( "one", "two", "three" );
print $thing;

#prints "three";
```

However, this is a really good example why `use strict;` *and* `use warnings;` is a REALLY good idea - because warnings tells you:

```
Useless use of a constant ("one") in void context at line ...
Useless use of a constant ("two") in void context at line ...
```

Try:

```
$VAR::phpmodules = ["php5-curl", "php5-mcrypt", "php-abc"];
```

Which will turn it into an array-ref. (You'll have to dereference it to print it though, with print `@$VAR::phpmodules` )

```
my $thing = [ "one", "two", "three" ];
print @$thing;
#prints onetwothree because no delimiter between array elements.
```

Or

```
@VAR::phpmodules = ("php5-curl", "php5-mcrypt", "php-abc");
```

e.g.

```
my @thing = ( "one", "two", "three" );
print @thing;
#prints "onetwothree"
```